# PostgreSQL 10 - IN and ANY performance inexplicable behaviour

Tags: sql, postgresql

I do selection from big table where id in array/list.
Checked several variants, result wonder me.

**1. Use ANY and ARRAY**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE,BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM cca_data_hours
    WHERE
    datetime = '2018-01-07 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND
    id_web_page = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2, 8, 3 /* ~50k ids */])
```

Result

```
"Index Scan using cca_data_hours_pri on cca_data_hours  (cost=0.28..576.79 rows=15 width=188) (actual time=0.035..0.998 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  Index Cond: (datetime = '2018-01-07 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"  Filter: (id_web_page = ANY ('{1,2,8,3, (...)"
" Rows Removed by Filter: 5"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"Planning time: 57.625 ms"
"Execution time: 1.065 ms"
```

---

**2. Use IN and VALUES**

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)
SELECT * FROM cca_data_hours
    WHERE
    datetime = '2018-01-07 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND
    id_web_page IN (VALUES (1),(2),(8),(3) /* ~50k ids */)
```

Result

```
"Hash Join  (cost=439.77..472.66 rows=8 width=188) (actual time=90.806..90.858 rows=6 loops=1)"
"  Hash Cond: (cca_data_hours.id_web_page = "*VALUES*".column1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=3"
"  ->  Index Scan using cca_data_hours_pri on cca_data_hours  (cost=0.28..33.06 rows=15 width=188) (actual time=0.035..0.060 rows=11 loops=1)"
"        Index Cond: (datetime = '2018-01-07 19:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=3"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=436.99..436.99 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=90.742..90.742 rows=4 loops=1)"
"        Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB"
"        ->  HashAggregate  (cost=434.99..436.99 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=90.709..90.717 rows=4 loops=1)"
"              Group Key: "*VALUES*".column1"
"              ->  Values Scan on "*VALUES*"  (cost=0.00..362.49 rows=28999 width=4) (actual time=0.008..47.056 rows=28999 loops=1)"
"Planning time: 53.607 ms"
"Execution time: 91.681 ms"
```

---

I expect case #2 will faster, but it is not like.
Why IN with VALUES slowelly?

Comment: I have never seen anyone use `column IN (VALUES (1),(2),(3))` like in an insert. Normally people use `column IN (1,2,3)`, which in Postgres gets internally transformed to `column = ANY (ARRAY[1,2,3])`.

Comment: I read this post https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/100x-faster-postgres-performance-by-changing-1-line

Comment: This is no panacea solution for every case. If it was, Postgres would do that behind the scenes already. Your first query executes in 1ms, what is your goal here?

Comment: I prepare optimized query now, later my table may have about 100m rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results, it looks like the old version wasn't using the available index to `key` in the given examples. The reason why `ANY (ARRAY[])` became faster is in version 9.2 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release-9-2.html

> Allow `indexed_col op ANY(ARRAY[...])` conditions to be used in plain index scans and index-only scans (Tom Lane)

The site where you got the suggestion from was about version 9.0